# Redux connecting dispatch to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a React app connected to Redux.

I've got an action creator which I use to fetch setup data.

Right at the top of my stateful component, I import it as such:

```
import { fetchSetup } from "../../store/actionCreators";
```

This is the actual fetchSetup() function:

```
export const fetchSetup = (clientID = 1) => async dispatch => {
  const clientIDObj = {
    user_id: clientID
  };
  await fetch(`${apiURLs.setup}`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(clientIDObj)
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
      console.log("fetchSetup()", json);
      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.FETCH_SETUP, payload: json });
    });
};
```

When I connect it to the Redux store as below, everything works great:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchSetup }
)(withRouter(Landing));
```

However, this is code cobbled together from various tutorials and such. I'm trying to connect another function in the way that I normally do it.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onUnauthenticated: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.UNAUTHENTICATED }),
    fetchSetupData: fetchSetup()
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Landing));
```

Although there are no errors, it simply never seems to actually execute my action creator. I never see any action dispatched in my Redux dev tools and I don't see any console.logs from inside the action creator function.

How can I connect my action creator in such a way that I can also connect other functions and they all work?

Comment: use   `fetchSetupData: fetchSetup`

Comment: When your are connecting like the first example you are sending an object as second argument to connect that looks like this: `{ fetchSetup: fetchSetup }` but if the key and value-variable has the same name it can be shortened. You are sending a reference to the function and not calling the function which is correct in this example because we are only "connecting" functions not calling them. In the second example you are calling `fetchSetup` (using `()`) and storing the inner returned function of `fetchSetup`.

Comment: @HarishSoni 's solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to use `mapDispatchToProps`. The one way which works for you is the method of providing `object` as mapDispatchToProps which redux internally then dispatches.

The second way which doens't work for you needs to have a function which is dispatched and not just called

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onUnauthenticated: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.UNAUTHENTICATED }),
    fetchSetupData: () => dispatch(fetchSetup())
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Landing));
```

Comment: Yours was the only solution that worked for me, thanks!